# Issues populating dynamic dropdown with React Hooks

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've never had any issue with this before but I've been struggling to get this to work so I'm hoping someone can notice something that I'm just missing. I'm pulling data from an API to populate a dropdown in my form. The data gets returned just fine and I assign in to my state using `useState` with no issues. However, when I try to map my results to options for my dropdown it never populates.

Here is my state and my useEffect function that I'm calling once when the page loads.

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/v1/users/find").then(res => {
        setUsers(res.data)
    })
}, [])
```

Like I said this all works with no issues. However this is where the issue is, my form:

```js
<div className="relative">
    <h3 className="text-2xl text-center font-bold mb-6">Create Item</h3>

    <select className="h-full w-full border-gray-300 px-2 transition-all border-blue rounded-sm" name="owner" onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e, 'owner')}>
        <option selected value=''>Owner</option>
        {users.map((i) => {
            <option value={i.name}>{i.name}</option>
        })}
    </select>
</div>
```

Once again I've never had any issues with this so I'm not sure why it doesn't seem to be populating. Appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the function passed to `.map()` doesn't return anything.  You can fix this by replacing the curly braces with parentheses:

```
{users.map((i) => (
    <option value={i.name}>{i.name}</option>
))}
```

When curly braces are used in an arrow function you need an explicit `return` statement to return a value.  Without curly braces there is an implicit `return` on the one line of the function body.  (In this case parentheses just help define that one line since it includes carriage returns.)

Comment: It's so weird that I've never had a problem before and I've never even known this. Thank you so much this worked perfectly!